# How I can import existing Django models into new pages

Tags: import, model, wagtail

I have information that I have obtained from the internet by **scraping** and I am writing it in a database table. I created the Django model to access that data. Now I want to publish it in a site made with WagTail. Is it possible to import it into a WagTail model? Could you use the wagtail API to do POST and publish that content?

Comment: If you can write a Django query expression to access the data, you can include that query expression on a Wagtail page, e.g. in a `get_context` method. http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#overriding-context